# Running a .bat script via gpedit on computer shutdown doesn't work

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I'm trying to run a basic `.bat` script with the following sample code:

```
echo some-text  > filename.txt
```

I'm attempting to set it up using `gpedit.msc` in `Computer Configuration > Window Settings > Scripts (Startup/Shutdown)`. However, it seems that the scripts don't execute.

I've tried different variations of other simple scripts. Tried doing it via Powershell and setting it up in the `PowerShell Scripts` tab. Tried to put the scripts in `C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts\Shutdown` and then add it to the list in gpedit. 
None of them seemed to work, despite the script executing with no problems while launching them manually.

I'm using Windows 10 Home and manually added the gpedit via other bat script.

Comment: Try using a full path. Security configuration is different than when run as a user. _•Shutdown scripts are run as Local System, and they have the full rights that are associated with being able to run as Local System._ from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn789190(v%3Dws.11)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Once again the `.bat` executes fine if ran manually, but not on system shutdown. As mentioned previously, I tried other simple scripts and they didn't execute as well.

Comment: I do not believe you can use group policies effectively or reliably on Windows 10 HOME.